# Pass command line arguments to the postinst script

Tags: args, deb

When creating a DEB package, how can I pass command line arguments to the `postinst` script? I'd like to read settings from an external file  and pass those as arguments.

Example:

```
$sudo dpkg -i foo.deb ./config.xml
```

Maybe there is some other solution?  Please advise.

Comment: You can't, at the point where you are installing a package with `dpkg`. But there are lots of solutions that might help. Maybe say more about what your problem is, rather than how you want to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly pass command-line arguments to `postinst`.  The usual solution to what you seem to be asking is to have a `configure` script, possibly with some values from `debconf` to customize it for the target system; if you don't need that, you can probably just hardcode it to read `/usr/share/lib/yourpackage/config.xml` and include that file in the package. (Maybe mark that as a `conffile` if you expect or even require the admin to change those settings.)

Answer (score 0):

Tried below

```
$ echo '<value>' | sudo dpkg -i foo.deb
```